# Subject subscribe, wait until function execution finished

Tags: asynchronous, rxjs

I have a question to observables. My case is, I have a subscription to subject and I would like to run a function in successful observable response. Once my function (foo) is finished (this function had to finished to continue logic in successful response), I would like to pass .next() method to my another subject. My problem is, I can't figure out, how can I wait until my function foo is finished and returned value. If I invoke setTimeout to my .next() method on my another subject, everything is working correctly. I simply would like to avoid setTimeout.
Schema of my code is:

```
this.customService.customSubject$.subscribe((response) => {
  this.someValueNeededInFoo = response;    
  this.foo(); //I need to wait for this function to be executed until I move on
  this.customService2.anotherSubject$.next(true); //That will be great if I can wait for this as well
  this.customService2.thirdSubject$.next(response); //This should invoke last
});

foo() {
 //do some logic stuff 
 return value;
}
```

If I use my code in subscribe like this:

```
this.customService.customSubject$.subscribe((response) => {
      this.someValueNeededInFoo = response;
      this.foo(); //I need to wait for this function to be executed until I move on
      
      setTimeout(() => {
      this.customService2.anotherSubject$.next(true); //That will be great if I can wait for this as well
      this.customService2.thirdSubject$.next(response); //This should invoke last
      }, 1000);
      
    });
```

then everything is working fine. I would like to avoid setTimeout, because in my case it's not really reliable. Can anyone guide me, what can I do here, to make a chain of those function calls?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not so much with observables, but the fact that `this.foo()` is an asynchronous method, which means it returns a promise.

You can simply place your logic in the `.then()` block after your call to `foo()`. This ensure it is executed after foo is done:

```
this.customService.customSubject$.subscribe(response => {
  this.someValueNeededInFoo = response;    
  this.foo().then(valFromFoo => {
     this.customService2.anotherSubject$.next(true);
     this.customService2.thirdSubject$.next(response);
  })
});
```

You can optionally use the `async/await` syntax instead of using `.then()`.  The following code is equivalent to the example above:

```
this.customService.customSubject$.subscribe(async response => {
  this.someValueNeededInFoo = response;    
  await this.foo();
  this.customService2.anotherSubject$.next(true);
  this.customService2.thirdSubject$.next(response);
  })
});
```

I'd like to mention that creating a bunch of subjects to emit values from others streams usually isn't necessary. You are typically able to define your streams off of one another.

Instead of doing something like this:

```
docIdSubject$ = new Subject<string>();
documentSubject$ = new Subject<Document>();

this.someService.id$.subscribe(
  id => this.docIdSubject$.next(id)
);

this.docIdSubject$.subcribe(
  docId => {
    this.docService.getDocument(docId).subscribe(
      document => this.documentSubject$.next(document)
    );
  );
);
```

You can define your observables off of the source observable with no need for subjects at all.

```
docId$ = this.someService.id$;
document$ = this.docId$.pipe(
   switchMap(id => docService.getDocument(id))
);
```

You can use pipeable operators to transform your stream however you'd like.  Notice there are no inner subscriptions.  I've found that it's much cleaner to put all the data transformation logic declaratively in the stream definition (inside `.pipe()`), leaving very little work to do in the actual subscription.

Notice now, you can just do `document$.subscribe()`.

Comment: did this help at all?